# UnregisterReceiver during phone call

Tags: android

I just turn off dynamic receiver during `EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK`.
Dynamic receiver was made in service controller which catches screen on/off action.

```
public class DisplayOnOffService extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT);
        final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new DiplayOnOffReceiver();
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter); // register my receiver
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        DisplayOnOffService getService() {
            return DisplayOnOffService.this;
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to call someone, I want to deactivated above receiver.
I mean unregister my receiver.

CallReciever:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    this.mContext = context;
    String state = extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

    if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)){
        final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new DiplayOnOffReceiver();
        mContext.unregisterReceiver(mReceiver); // this is not working at all.
    }
}
```

`mContext.unregister` does not work that I wish.
I'd like to stop(unregister) my DiplayOnOffReceiver.
How can I resolve my problem?

Comment: You are unregistering a new object..for this you need to pass same object for registering and unrierster

Comment: Oh my Goodness.. I got see a little.